# java-8-oracle (1.8.0_66) problem with PrintAssembly "Could not load hsdis-amd64.so"

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

I'm trying to run my programs with `-XX:+PrintAssembly` options but I always get message like:

> *Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: PrintAssembly is enabled; turning on DebugNonSafepoints to gain additional output Could not load
>   hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled*

I downloaded the hsdis-amd64.so from Kenai: https://kenai.com/projects/base-hsdis/downloads

I have build this library myself with http://sourceforge.net/projects/fcml/files/fcml-1.1.1/ project.

I put it everywhere "google says":

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64/
```

with names:

```
hsdis-amd64.so
libhsdis-amd64.so
hsdis.so
libhsdis.so
```

I have tried even set manually export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/`

... and all for nothing.

No more Google results no more combination of above solutions :-(

Could anyone can help me?

Answer (score 11):

First install `libhsdis0-fcml` as described in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/892413/523336)<sup>1</sup>:

```
sudo apt-get install libhsdis0-fcml
```

This only installs it for OpenJDK. You are, however, using `java-8-oracle`, so you'll need to copy it over there. Here's the *exact* copy command that worked for me:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/hsdis-amd64.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/hsdis-amd64.so
```

If that's still not working, you might try an `strace` to see where your `java` is looking. I used:

```
strace -f java -XX:CompileCommand='print, *.*' ... |& grep hsdis
```

to get output like this:

```
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libhsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libhsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libhsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/hsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/hsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/hsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/hsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>
[pid 10783] open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/hsdis-amd64.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 14
```

You can see that the places and names you were trying are definitely among those the JDK searches (in my case, it probably would have searched more places, but stopped since the last location above is where it found the shared object).

Note that you definitely need the `-f` flag to `strace` since the actual JVM is launched as a child process of the original `java` command.

Among the issues `strace` might reveal is a permissions issue. I only needed read perms on the library for the user launching `java`.

My `java -version` output:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Really, this is just a way to get a (presumably working) `hsdis.so` file in a package-manager friendly way. You could always just download it directly from one of the various sources as well.

Answer (score 5):

Install package `libhsdis0-fcml`:

```
apt-get install libhsdis0-fcml
```

It should provide all necessary libraries (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libhsdis0-fcml/filelist)