# Could not load hsdis-arm.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled

Tags: java, arm, gradle

I am using a beaglebone black with ubuntu bionic(armv7hf) and I'm trying to run:

```
gradle
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
, tid=19
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0+24) (build 11+24-Ubuntu-118.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11+24-Ubuntu-118.04, mixed mode, serial gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# J 11 c2 java.lang.StringCoding.encodeUTF8_UTF16([BZ)[B java.base@11 (369 bytes) @ 0xb406b900 [0xb406b8a0+0x00000060]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/bin/false" (or dumping to /jason/core.1)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
/jason/hs_err_pid1.log
Could not load hsdis-arm.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled


#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

[error occurred during error reporting (), id 0x4, SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0xb6e6489c]
```

If i try to run maven I get:

```
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:                                                                                                                                                 
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
, tid=24                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0+24) (build 11+24-Ubuntu-118.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11+24-Ubuntu-118.04, mixed mode, serial gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# J 16 c2 java.lang.StringCoding.encodeUTF8_UTF16([BZ)[B java.base@11 (369 bytes) @ 0xb403d800 [0xb403d7a0+0x00000060]                                                                                            
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/bin/false" (or dumping to /java_rosbridge/core.5)                                                                               
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /java_rosbridge/hs_err_pid5.log
 java.lang.StringCoding::encodeUTF8_UTF16 (369 bytes)
 total in heap  [0xb403d688,0xb403dcf4] = 1644
 relocation     [0xb403d76c,0xb403d798] = 44
 main code      [0xb403d7a0,0xb403db30] = 912
 stub code      [0xb403db30,0xb403db4c] = 28
 metadata       [0xb403db4c,0xb403db64] = 24
 scopes data    [0xb403db64,0xb403dc24] = 192
 scopes pcs     [0xb403dc24,0xb403dcb4] = 144
 dependencies   [0xb403dcb4,0xb403dcb8] = 4
 handler table  [0xb403dcb8,0xb403dce8] = 48
 nul chk table  [0xb403dce8,0xb403dcf4] = 12
Could not load hsdis-arm.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I think it is something similar to [java-8-oracle (1.8.0_66) problem with PrintAssembly "Could not load hsdis-amd64.so"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710392/java-8-oracle-1-8-0-66-problem-with-printassembly-could-not-load-hsdis-amd64)

However, I can't find a lib with the name libhsdis0-fcml
I checked and it is only avaible for amd64 and i386

Ideas?

Comment: Here are binaries for JDK 9 from BellSoft: https://www.bell-sw.com/jvm-tools.html